# can you look this problem and solution?

Tags: self-study, geometric-distribution

A company produces IC (integrated-circuit) chips.
(a) The produced chips are tested one at a time until a good chip is found. If the
probability that at least three tests are needed equals 0.0225. Find the
defective rate (percentage of defective items) for the factory.

**and solution is given as :**
Let the probability of finding a defective chip be p.

therefore, probability of finding a non defective chip is 1-p.

Let X be a random variable such that:

X: No of tests until a good chip is found.

Given that,

P(X>=3)=0.0225

or, 1-P(X<3) = 0.0225

or, P(X=1)+P(X=2)=1-0.0225=0.9775

or, **(1-p)** + p(1-p) =0.9775

ı did not understand part of p(x=1)=(1-p).
ı think this must be just **p** because of geometric formulation. which one is true ? ı hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

$p(x=1)=1-p$ is correct. If you like, you may express it as $p(x=1)=p^0(1-p)^1=1-p$.

Comment: f(x) =( (1 − p)^(x − 1) )* p when ı substitude x=1 it equals p?

Comment: You already said "Let the probability of finding a defective chip be p", and "probability of finding a non defective chip is 1-p". Thus, $p(x=1) = p^{x-1}(1-p)^x$.

Comment: now ı understand thank you